# Training model throwing "non-conformable arguments" error

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning

So I am using a feed forward neural net for a multi class classification. The data is as follows:
7500 columns, 57 rows, 1st column is predictor, Pred, which has values 0, 1 and 2.

```
train_nn <- cbind(class.ind(as.factor(train$Pred)),train[,c(-1)] )
test_nn <- cbind(class.ind(as.factor(test$Pred)),test[,c(-1)] )
names(train_nn) <- c("l1","l2","l3",names(train[,c(-1)]))
n <- names(train_nn)
f <- as.formula(paste("l1 + l2 + l3 ~", paste(n[!n %in% "Pred"], collapse = " + ")))
modelffnn <- neuralnet(f,data=train_nn,hidden=c(18,15, 10,5),linear.output=F)
```

The error I am getting on running the last line of code is:

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments

I have looked up and this error seems to have previously occured in many instances while using compute().

I am not sure as to why this issue has come, and how to resolve this.

Comment: Copied from close vote reason panel: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]."

Comment: @42- Not sure on what basis is it non-reproducable. Data has been explained, and the entire code to the error without the libraries given.

Comment: @Raj, surely you cannot expect someone who does not have your data to paste your code in R and run it to see what `train` is made up of? This is clearly non-reproducible. To be reproducible - the code must be able to run.

Comment: It is obvious that the number of columns in `neurons[[i]]` do not match the number of rows in `weights[[i]]` -- which is what is necessary to do matrix multiplication. Why that is or what can be done? I'm not sure.